# unstructured.UnstructuredList caused lots of reflect.go trace

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I'm trying to use the `unstructured.UnstructuredList` to reuse come logic for `configmap` and `secret`.

However, after adding the `ListAndDeployReferredObject`, I started to see tons of trace as `Starting reflector *unstructured.Unstructured` was added to my log file.

Am I doing something odd or I'm missing some setting for using the `unstructured.Unstructured`?

Thanks in advance.

```golang
func (r *ReconcileSubscription) ListAndDeployReferredObject(instance *appv1alpha1.Subscription, gvk schema.GroupVersionKind, refObj referredObject) error {
    insName := instance.GetName()
    insNs := instance.GetNamespace()
    uObjList := &unstructured.UnstructuredList{}

    uObjList.SetGroupVersionKind(gvk)

    opts := &client.ListOptions{Namespace: insNs}
    err := r.Client.List(context.TODO(), uObjList, opts)

    if err != nil && !errors.IsNotFound(err) {
        klog.Errorf("Failed to list referred objects with error %v ", err)
        return err
    }
    // other logics... 
}
```

```golang
I0326 23:05:58.955589   95169 reflector.go:120] Starting reflector *unstructured.Unstructured (10m0s) from pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20191016111102-bec269661e48/tools/cache/reflector.go:96
...
I0326 23:15:18.718932   95169 reflector.go:158] Listing and watching *unstructured.Unstructured from pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.0.0-20191016111102-bec269661e48/tools/cache/reflector.go:96
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out these prints are normal, since we are using the dynamic client on our controller for caches